# How to join 3 tables and order by date of all 3?

Tags: sql, join

I have 3 tables,

albums, videos and stories.

All 3 have a date column and each connected with subject_id column.

I want to select all albums, videos and stories of subject_id ordered by date, How can i do that?

Now i have this query :

```
SELECT albums.*, videos.*, stories.*
FROM albums
LEFT JOIN videos
ON videos.subject_id = albums.subject_id
RIGHT JOIN stories
ON stories.subject_id = albums.subject_id
ORDER BY albums.date
```

Will this do the trick or am i missing something?
Because i want the dates not be ordered just by albums, stories could have older enteries then albums and so on.

Comment: so whats the problem with your query?

Comment: it dosen't order them as expected...

Comment: much better if you can have sample result

Comment: This is a sample query just wanted to understand the logic behind it, how to order 3 tables by 1 shared column, havn't decided what results i need yet

Comment: it's hard to get what you really wanted to do, Scott has provided an answer but it seems it doesn't do what you really wanted.

Comment: This query would not result in one date column, it would result in 3 date columns - an album date, a video date and a story date.  To get what I think you're looking for, you'll need a function with the logic to choose which date you want to use for a particular record, like - "logic_function(album.date, video.date, stories.date) AS date", and then you can order by date.  What functions are available to you depends on exactly what database you're using.

Comment: You probably need a `UNION`, not a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, assuming you always want to sort in Ascending order by the earliest date in the set, you could do:

```
ORDER BY LEAST(albums.date, videos.date, stories.date)
```

"LEAST" is an Oracle function that returns the minimum (i.e. earliest) value in the set.  If you're on a database without a simliar command you could use a CASE statement:

```
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN albums.date <= videos.date AND albums.date <= stories.date THEN albums.date
    WHEN videos.date <= albums.date AND videos.date <= stories.date THEN videos.date
    ELSE stories.date
```

Although I'm not sure this is what you want either.  You're going to have a large row with all the album, video, and story information on one line.  If you want a row for each different album, video, or story, then you probably want a UNION rather than a set of JOINs, although then you'll have to make sure you use the same fields.  For example, if you had a title field in each table that you wanted to see, you could use:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 'Album' as RowType, album_title as title, subject_id, date from albums
    UNION
    SELECT 'Video' as RowType, video_title as title, subject_id, date from videos
    UNION
    SELECT 'Story' as RowType, story_title as title, subject_id, date from stories
    )
ORDER BY subject_id, date
```

Which would give the sort order I believe you wanted (or you can take subject_id out of the ORDER BY if you preferred).  The only thing about the UNION is that you have to return the same columns in each underlying query, so if you want vastly different information from albums than from videos, it will get tricky.

Comment: Thank you chip this is exactly what i needed! forgot about UNION :)

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to replace

```
ORDER BY albums.date
```

with

```
ORDER BY albums.date, videos.date, stories.date
```

This will order by album date first, then video date within that, and story date within that.  I think that will get you what you're looking for.

Comment: I want them to order it together not after the other

Comment: @eric.itzhak what does ordering it together mean?

Comment: All 3 of the tables have date column and i want the result to be ordered by all of the dates not grouped by tables. meaning if albums has 2 rows, one in 2012 and one in 2010, and stories have one in 2011 and one in 2009, so the result will be 2009-2010-2011-2012 (ofcourse those are full dates)

Comment: Then you have to use something other than a join.